# PCL Tutorial voxel_grid Permission Denied

Tags: ros, pcl, permission, voxel-grid, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am new to ROS, Ubuntu, and PCL.  I have Ubuntu 11.10.  I am attempting to complete the ROS PCL Tutorials at http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl/Tutorials.  I got stuck at step 4.1.

I was unable to get the ./voxel_grid command to work in the linked part of the tutorial at the PCL website at http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/voxel_grid.php.  I receive the following errors:

```
albertchi@albertchi-e6510:~/my_pcl_tutorial$ ./voxel_grid
bash: ./voxel_grid: No such file or directory
albertchi@albertchi-e6510:~/my_pcl_tutorial$ ./voxel_grid.cpp
bash: ./voxel_grid.cpp: Permission denied
```

I tried: albertchi@albertchi-e6510:~$ chmod 777 my_pcl_tutorial, but this did not change the output.

I moved on to the next step in the tutorial (the second part of step 4.1), and tried:

```
albertchi@albertchi-e6510:~$ rosmake my_pcl_tutorial
[ rosmake ] rosmake starting...                                                 
[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['my_pcl_tutorial']                         
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory /home/albertchi/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121022-112526
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['my_pcl_tutorial'] to:
[]                            
[ rosmake ] WARNING: The following args could not be parsed as stacks or packages: ['my_pcl_tutorial']
[ rosmake ] ERROR: No arguments could be parsed into valid package or stack names.
```

Obviously, this was unsuccessful as well.  Suggestions would be appreciated.  I am hoping it is something simple because I am new.

Amanda

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46469/pcl-tutorial-voxel_grid-permission-denied/) by [Amanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3435/amanda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2012-10-22**:
What does executing `ls -la ~/my_pcl_tutorial` give?

**Comment by [Amanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3435/amanda/) on 2012-10-22**:
total 5568

drwxrwxrwx  4 albertchi albertchi    4096 2012-10-22 10:56 .

drwxr-xr-x 36 albertchi albertchi    4096 2012-10-22 09:39 ..

-rw-rw-r--  1 albertchi albertchi    1569 2012-10-19 16:33 CMakeLists.txt

-rw-rw-r--  1 albertchi albertchi    1254 2012-10-08 15:06 CMakeLists.txt~

**Comment by [Amanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3435/amanda/) on 2012-10-22**:
-rw-rw-r--  1 albertchi albertchi     761 2012-10-08 15:06 example.cpp

drwxrwxr-x  3 albertchi albertchi    4096 2012-10-08 15:01 include

-rw-rw-r--  1 albertchi albertchi     120 2012-10-08 15:01 mainpage.dox

-rw-rw-r--  1 albertchi albertchi      41 2012-10-08 15:01 Makefile

**Comment by [Amanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3435/amanda/) on 2012-10-22**:
-rw-rw-r--  1 albertchi albertchi     367 2012-10-08 15:01 manifest.xml

drwxrwxr-x  2 albertchi albertchi    4096 2012-10-08 15:01 src

-rw-rw-r--  1 albertchi albertchi 5649007 2012-10-19 16:51 table_scene_lms400.pcd

-rw-rw-r--  1 albertchi albertchi    1559 2012-10-22 10:56 voxel_grid.cpp

**Comment by [Amanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3435/amanda/) on 2012-10-22**:
-rw-rw-r--  1 albertchi albertchi    1591 2012-10-22 10:56 voxel_grid.cpp~

Sorry this is so long and broken up.  Is there a better way for me to post a response in the future?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-22**:
Instead of creating a lot of comments, it's better to edit the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to set up a ROS workspace before you can compile your own packages. Have a look at [this page](http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Overlays) and [this tutorial](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Amanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3435/amanda/) on 2012-10-22**:
Thank you for the guidance.  I attempted to do this using two methods:

I tried to add the my_pcl_tutorial file to the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH using:

albertchi@albertchi-e6510:~$ rosws set ~/my_pcl_tutorial

albertchi@albertchi-e6510:~$ source /home/albertchi/setup.sh

but it returned the same error.

**Comment by [Amanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3435/amanda/) on 2012-10-22**:
Second Method:
I copied the entire my_pcl_tutorial folder into the fuerte_workspace folder and did:

albertchi@albertchi-e6510:~$ rosws set ~/fuerte_workspace/my_pcl_tutorial

albertchi@albertchi-e6510:~$ source /home/albertchi/setup.sh

but it returned the same error.

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-22**:
You must source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash, not /home/albertchi/setup.sh. The latter file should even not exist at all.

**Comment by [Amanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/3435/amanda/) on 2012-10-22**:
I originally ran source /home/albertchi/setup.sh because the output of rosws set ~/fuerte_workspace/my_pcl_tutorial told me to run that command specifically. Idk why. I ran

albertchi@albertchi-e6510:~$ source ~/fuerte_workspace/setup.bash

and I received the same error as before.

**Comment by [baogege](https://answers.ros.org/users/22605/baogege/) on 2015-08-08**:
do you solve it?I have the same problem.I am using ubuntu12.04+groovy,and I also source ~/my_ws/devel/setup.bash          can you help me?